# Detecting closed routes in orientdb

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

How can I detect closed routes (circles) following different types of edges in OrientDB?
Let me give an example. I have two types of vertices, Ideas and Persons, and I have two types of edges, submitted_by and commented_by. No I want to find all "co-commented" ideas. Two ideas are co-commented if the submitter of the one idea is the commentator of the other. My approach was to follow the outgoing commentator-edges, see what ideas these persons submitted, following again the commentators to these ideas and see whether the original idea is among these. My problem is that OrientDB doesn't allow me to use aliases for "from-expressions" like class names, and so I cannot compare the id of the first idea with the ids of the ideas I get when following the edges.
I have to say, that I'am completely new to OrientDB and also to GraphDBs in general. So maybe there is a simple answer to that problem. But an answer would definitely help me to better understand how you typically work with OrientDB and maybe that answer might be helpful for others as well.

Comment: You could store values in variable on context to be retrieved later, by using the LET, but I'd need an example of your query and your schema

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I formulated the query like this: `select id from Idea let $i2 = out_IdeaSubmitter.in_IdeaCommentor.out_IdeaSubmitter.in_IdeaCommentor where id in $i2.id`.

Comment: I reformulated the query as: `select id from Idea let $i2 = out('IdeaSubmitter').in('IdeaCommentor').out('IdeaSubmitter').in('IdeaCommentor') where id in $i2.id`. The result of this query seems to be correct, but it is different to the one above. Why?